# React Testing Library + React Query - promise isn't resolved while testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, react-query

I'm using React 18, React Testing Library 14.0.0, and React Query 3.3. Everything is working like a charm in the browser (real user) context. But while testing I am experiencing some problems.

My component (simplified):

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query"

export const Dashboard = () => {
    const { data } = useQuery(...)
    const { data: project } = useQuery(...)

return <div data-testid="project-name">{project.name}</div>
```

The test:

```
import { ReactElement, Suspense } from "react"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import { QueryClient } from "react-query"

export const testRenderer = (test: ReactElement) => 
render(<Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
  <QueryClientProvider
    client={
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            suspense: true,
          },
        },
      })
    }
  >{test}</QueryClientProvider>
</Suspense>);
```

The test:

```
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

test("render it", async () => {
  const { getByTestId } = testRenderer(<Dashboard />);

  await waitFor(async () => await findByTestId("project-name"));
  await waitFor(() => findByTestId("project-name"));
});
```

As a result, I see the **FAIL** *Timed out in waitFor.*:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>loading...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So it's pretty apparent `<Suspense />` is waiting for the react-queries to be finished before rendering the real component body.

When I wrap react queries into a try/catch I see as a result of `console.log(error)`: `Promise { <pending> }` so the promises are pending for some reason while I reach `waitFor`.

How can I fix it or even debug deeply what's wrong with react-query?